# computer goes to sleep / freezes even though I have high performance setting set in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power

So my computer should not be going to sleep but I think it is because when I play a flash movie on videoBB or another similar site for longer than 30 mins or so the computer fan goes off and even though my computer screen is on It takes forever to open the task manager or do anything. I have the power setting set to high performance and I went into the BIOS power settings but there is no mention about enabling/disabling a power saver mode even though it looks like there might be one... Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` and ensure `Put the computer to sleep:` is set to `Never`.